# send_download undefined in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create an api with the phoenix framework that sends a pdf back to the client, but I'm running into an error saying that send_download is not defined.

```
== Compilation error in file web/controllers/test_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/test_controller.ex:9: undefined function send_download/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:121: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
MacBook-Pro-2:coetic_report_generator waynegretsky$
```

Here's my actual file where it's used (web/controllers/test_controller.ex):

```
defmodule CoeticReportGenerator.TestController do
  use CoeticReportGenerator.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    input_file = "markdown.md"
    output_file = "output/markdown_file.md"

    System.cmd("pandoc", ["-s", "-o", output_file, input_file]) 
    send_download(conn,{:file, output_file})
    #  text conn, "IT WORKS."
  end
end
```

Here's the router.ex file:

```
defmodule CoeticReportGenerator.Router do
  use CoeticReportGenerator.Web, :router

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json", "json-api"]
  end

  scope "/api", CoeticReportGenerator do
    pipe_through :api

    get "test", TestController, :index
  end
end
```

When I created it, I used no-html and no-brunch, in case that's relevant. Is there any reason that I would end up with this error? When I comment it out and render text, it works fine.

Comment: Which version of Phoenix are you on? `send_download` was added in 1.3.0.

Comment: Based on the pasted snippet, it doesn't look like 1.3 for me. It has a namespace `Web`.